# How does natural attacks interact with double slice and other dual weapon fighting feats?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, two-weapon-fighting, natural-weapon

I want to make a character that has multiple natural attacks (jaw, claws and tail). I want to use them in a way that seems good for me. I looked at the dual weapon warrior archetype, and it felt like it could work for me, but I want to be sure it would work RAW.

To be clear, what I ask is can I use double slice with my two claws? With claw and jaw (or tail)? (I take double slice as an example, but my question is for the entire archetype.)

Comment: Have you considered Monk for [Flurry of Blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=9)? That allows you to make two attacks, and they can be any of your unarmed attacks.

Comment: @ESCE I wanted to play thief rogue so I can focus on dexterity, maybe I will take monk archetype to get flurry of blow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see about the rules.

[Unarmed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=199), CRB 283:

> An unarmed attack uses your body rather than a manufactured weapon. An
> unarmed attack isn't a weapon, though it's categorized with weapons
> for weapon groups, and it might have weapon traits.

[Double slice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=356), CRB 144:

> Requirements You are wielding two melee weapons, each in a different hand.

Since unarmed says it's not a weapon, you are RAW not welding two melee weapons that are required for double slice.

As for RAI, striking with two natural weapons at the same time sounds reasonable.

Comment: Your last section is a little confusing. You seem to say the restriction makes sense, but also that ignoring it makes sense. Also, I don't feel like RAI applies since it's pretty clear that any interpretation or intention of the rules is that claws, as unarmed attacks, are not weapons and don't qualify for "You are wielding two [...] weapons"

Answer (score 2):

### Double Slice requires weapons

As vonPryz accurately points out, Unarmed attacks are not weapons and are only included on weapon lists for convenience; Double Slice specifically requires that you are wielding two melee *weapons*. Because of this, you cannot use Double Slice or any similarly designed Action/Activity with unarmed attacks.

### Balance

Double Slice is a very powerful ability, particularly for the level(s) it's available at. The "cost" of Double Slice is the required weapons; allowing it with claws removes the need to draw weapons and the risk of being disarmed. While the two actions to draw two melee weapons is a significant cost (albeit for one round, and not if you are able to walk around with weapons out), being disarmed is not a *common* occurrence (in my experience), making both very circumstantial concerns.

In one of my groups, we have ruled that it is allowed *only* for claw (or similar) unarmed attacks (not fists, jaws, etc.) to keep it "in line" with typical Dual Weapon combat thematically and numerically. Claws' damage will almost definitely lag slightly behind typical melee weapon choices, more than making up the difference compared to the other costs mentioned above. But this ruling isn't right for all groups, so talk to your GM since this is not the "correct" ruling.

Answer (score 1):

The Dual-Weapon Warrior archetype has similar restrictions in each of its feats, that you are wielding two weapons in your hands. Unfortunately [unarmed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=199) attacks are not considered weapons and don't qualify as meeting these requirements, so this archetype doesn't really work out for your character.

There are some alternative archetypes that do work with unarmed attacks, some generic and some uncommon options specific to the Pathfinder campaign setting.

### Generic Archetypes

[Monk](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=8) as an archetype gives access to some relevant good monk feats as well as eventually getting Flurry of Blows, though the requirements of both Strength 14 and Dexterity 14 might be tricky depending on what you're looking to do.

The [Wrestler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=127) archetype offers some solid advantages, mostly around using Athletics with your free hands because you're not wielding a weapon.

The [Martial Artist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=67) archetype lets you access many stances that give unique unarmed attacks or other benefits while fighting without weapons, if for some reason monk doesn't make sense.

### Uncommon Archetypes

[Jalmeri Heavenseeker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=86) offers a lot of what the monk does, but with a few alternative options that might be interesting (and without the ability requirements).

[Student of Perfection](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=18) has some interesting focus spells and the *[perfect strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=542)* focus spell in particular for unarmed attacks.